# How is a linear time invariant system a dynamic system

Tags: definition, dynamical-systems

This question may be a bit elementary, but I am having some confusion with understanding the basics of a linear time invariant system.

My goal was trying to understand what an [impulse response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_response) was, since a linear time invariant system is characterized by its impulse response.  Wikipedia said that this was output of a [dynamic system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_system) when presented with an impulse.

From what I understand a dynamic system something where if you have a state, there is an equation that dictates what the next state is for some future time, giving examples like mechanics, where velocity tells you the position is next.  However, this seems different from what the linear time invariant systems does, since it seems to be like a function, having a clear input x(t) and output y(t), and the output does not influence the input.

So how exactly is an impulse inputted into a dynamic system? And what exactly is the output of a dynamic system? I tried looking into the [formal definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_system_(definition)), but it seemed too abstract, and I could not figure out how to get an input and output from it.

Answer (score 1):

You have something like $L[y]=x$. Now suppose that you can decompose $x(t)=\sum x_kb(t-k)$ or $x(t)=\int_0^\infty x(s)b(t-s)\,ds$. Then it is sufficient to solve $L[y_b]=b$ once and then use the linearity and time shift invariance to get any other solution as
$$
y=\sum x_ky_b(t-k)~~\text{ or }~~y(t)=\int_0^\infty x(s)y_b(t-s)\,ds.
$$
This only works for LTI systems, but fortunately lots of practical applications can be approximated by such systems.

In more mathematical terms the idea is the same as that of a Green's function.